# We’re Adding our Subprocessors to the GDPR Section of Our Legal Portal

Tags: discussion, legal, announcements, gdpr

As part of our continued effort to ensure compliance with the [GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/), we are publishing a list of our subprocessors - a list of third party vendors who process personal information for each of our services.  This list will be updated as alterations occur. Note, there have not been any changes made to how we process personal data. We’re simply publishing this list for additional transparency about the vendors we work with.

The new [subprocessor page](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/subprocessors) is linked within the [primary GDPR page](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr) and can also be accessed from the left navigation menu of the [legal portal](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/).

We’re happy to answer any questions you have about this, but we can’t give legal advice (such as interpreting the GDPR or other regulations).

Answer (score 12):

Thank you for going the extra mile here. This added transparency is really appreciated.

### As a suggestion for improvement:

I see that there is a lot of overlap in the three tables for teams.

Perhaps you can condense them in this format:

| Sub-Processor | Activities | Basic | Business | Enterprise |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chargify | Self-serve subscription management & billing | X | X |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| Zuora | Subscription management & billing |  | X | X |

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I believe the separation was deliberate but I will pass this on to our legal team.

Comment: @Des yeah each format has its pro's and con's. But with so much overlap between tables I think this works better, as it reads in a friendlier way.

Comment: @Des, there's actually (at first glance) 100% duplication of company name and service (sub-processor and activities), with the six headings being the majority of the change (were two services offered there could be a split row after the first column). -- The right half of Luuklag's table could be the categories with the rightmost (4th) column spilt in three for Teams. That would remove the repetition from that webpage, probably compressing to one third the size; resulting in no loss of information or confusion.