# Race condition with commenting and migration

Tags: support, migration

I was writing a comment on [How can we post more questions on AskUbuntu without the 40 minute rule?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306115/how-can-we-post-more-questions-on-askubuntu-without-the-40-minute-rule?noredirect=1). As soon as I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the question got migrated to meta but my comment wasn't copied over there. The timestamp of comment and migration is 2021-01-08 12:47:43Z.

Possibly race condition?

Comment: Shouldn't this be set to a [tag:bug] question?

Comment: @MarkGiraffe May be. But I avoided that since it may happen that the question was hypothetically migrated before my comment and my comment got posted since there are some milliseconds required to lock the *original* post.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe That's not required. The [tag:support] tag is perfectly valid for asking whether or not something is a bug; as a matter of fact, the tag [tag:possible-bug] is a synonym of [tag:support].

Comment: (If going there, note the [cookie consent trial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358/we-re-adding-more-user-controls-for-cookie-consent) (currently only on Ask Ubuntu (this week)).)

Comment: Did the comment get posted to the original? The last comment I see from you on the original says “related:” and has a link to https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18745/816190?

Answer (score 1):

This would only be a problem if the comment now existed somehow at Ask Ubuntu. The behaviour here is the same as if you'd waited another five minutes before trying to submit your comment.

While technically there is a race here, it's only a "race condition bug" if it results in some otherwise illegal state.

Comment: I expect the post to be locked even before 5 mins. Thus, encountering *unexpected error* while posting comment.

Comment: Nope, it's an illegal state. Either the comment should have been allowed on the origin question and then migrated over to the destination question (if the comment was posted before migration), or the comment shouldn't have been allowed on the origin (if the comment was posted after migration, since migration locks the origin).

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog you are not describing states. Those are processes. Every state in the process, including the final state (a migrated question and the lack of a comment), was perfectly valid.