# Link to cookie policy doesn't work in 'Accept all cookies' popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, cookie-policy

I received this popup:

[image]

When clicking on 'Cookie Policy' it links to the current page url (with a `#` at the end).

Comment: According to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358/we-re-adding-more-user-controls-for-cookie-consent#comment1200232_359358) on the [Announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359358/282094) it probably (is supposed to) [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy#C0003-list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `2021.2.12.38568`

Comment: The `X` to close the popup has gone as well, is that by-design?