# Link to cookie policy doesn't work in "Accept all cookies" popup

Tags: bug, user-interface, legal, privacy, cookie-policy

See also, a more narrow bug [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360867) (tagged "status-completed", incorrectly(?)).

Upon visiting some SE sites (e.g. superuser.com), logged in or not, I receive this popup:

[image: screenshot of broken cookie alert with non-functional button labeled "accept all cookies"]

1. The "Customize settings" button shows a little spinner for a moment, but otherwise does nothing. Repeated presses do not show the spinner.
2. A comment on the question above reports, "it probably (is supposed to) link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy#C0003-list)." That link brings me to a section of the cookie policy, with no controls visible.

At the bottom of the Targeting Cookies section of the [Stack Exchange Cookie Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy) page, you say:

> You can withdraw any consent to the use of cookies or manage any other cookie preferences by visiting our [Cookie Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy#) or clicking on the bottom of every page of our websites.

3. Clicking the "Cookie Setting" fake link (javascript?) on that page, again, does nothing.
4. The sentence quoted above also mentions I may click "on the bottom of every page of our websites." Below is what I see at the bottom of any of your websites. What does "the bottom of every page of our websites" then mean when looking for cookie & consent controls?
   [image: A screenshot of the bottom of a stack overflow question list, which has many links, but none related to cookies]

Comment: So, what browser are you on? What OS? Any plugins / ad blockers / virus scanning / firewalls? Can you open the developer console and check for errors there? Either in the network tab or the console? The competent experts will then try to work out where the problem might be.

Comment: No repro on Firefox Nightly 88.0a1 + uBlock Origin for the first issue. Check the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors; check your adblocker. I can, however, confirm that the “Cookie Settings” link in the [Targeting Cookies section](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy#C0004-list) does nothing (no network activity, no error). The footer on Super User has a (working) “Cookie Settings” link under “Company”.

Comment: I chose to omit that info it to keep focus where it belongs: on the implementation of the cookie settings workflow. If users are blocking third-party javascripts, or blocking ad domains, why would that interfere with a first-party page of controls? I'll add that info at some point to perhaps keep this productive, but I assert the burden here should not be shifted to users in general. Privacy controls should Just Work™.

Comment: On Super User I do have that cookie setting link in the footer and it does work (I'm on Chrome / W10, uBlock running)

Comment: @JoelReid No, it doesn’t work for _you_, so you are in the best position to include all relevant debug information. Help the company help you. If it turns out you’re running an [unsupported browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/289905) or nobody can reproduce these issues, this bug report will just be closed and deleted.

Comment: @SebastianSimon As I said, I am the one with symptoms, and will participate, but I still hold that "It doesn't work for someone" should not be true of privacy controls.

Comment: @JoelReid What is the point of this comment? It’s just a bug. Why do you think you should provide _fewer_ details in privacy-related bug reports? I don’t see how this makes sense.

Comment: The “Cookie Settings” link in the [Targeting Cookies section](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy#C0004-list) also doesn’t work with uBlock Origin disabled, or in the latest Google Chrome. Clicking the link expects an element with ID `onetrust-banner-sdk` to exist, but it doesn’t — no matter if all resources are able to load, or some are blocked; I tried disabling Cookie blockers, uBlock Origin, etc. Definitely a bug here.

Comment: Early signs point to cloudflare blocking my loading of your use of https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js  My comments above were all to keep this focused on SE's implementation choices. E.g. here, why is a third-party javascript needed to change privacy settings?

Comment: On SO that script is not loaded at all it seems. The click handler from /legal works, the Onetrust div missing causes it to stall as it has no place to show the info it fetched.

Comment: I get a `503 Service Unavailable` error when I click `Accept all Cookies` and it never works. Always get this popup. The error message: `GET https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js net::ERR_ABORTED 503 (Service Unavailable)`

Comment: I faced the same issues for month. Disable uBlock Origin and refresh and accept all cookies. Then re-enable uBlock.

Comment: I had this issue come back when I started using tor, which cookielaw is apparently hostile to. I "allowlisted" a non-tor direct connection, to cookielaw.org only, in `network.proxy.no_proxies_on` in about:config.