# cdn.cookielaw.org is blocked by my browser

Tags: support, cookie-policy

When navigating Stack Exchange, I get this error in my browser's console

> The resource from “https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

I'm using Seamonkey.  My browser is also continuously asking about my cookie settings, but only on Stack Exchange.  Is this a problem with the site or with my browser?

Seamonkey says about this error:

> Note: X-Content-Type-Options only apply request-blocking due to nosniff for request destinations of "script" and "style". However, it also enables Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) protection for HTML, TXT, JSON and XML files (excluding SVG image/svg+xml).

Comment: There is this report on the meta of AskUbuntu that seems similar: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19480/cookie-consent-banner-wont-stay-away but that is  for a firefox browser. Not sure if SeaMonkey is spin-off.

Comment: Nowadays a large part of the code is based on Firefox's.

Comment: Adding a link to the [Cookie consent announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358/we-re-adding-more-user-controls-for-cookie-consent) for reference.

Comment: Does StackExchange expect people to whitelist cookielaw.org?  I didn't find it on the cookie consent announcement, neither that a third party would be used.

Comment: Not sure about FF itself (because it's overruled by another extension and a DNS sinkhole), but both uBlock and pihole blocks cookielaw. Not sure what the privacy implications of this are

Comment: It is strange that I don't seem to have a cookie from them nor do I see their domain so I'm also wondering for what purpose that domain gets loaded and what its role is in giving consent. This needs an answer from SE devs.

Comment: I've got uBlock Origin, but cookielaw doesn't appear in its logs. That and the console message indicate the block is from Seamonkey - or Firefox - itself.

Comment: No repro, might be something on your side. (malware, or your browser doing something on its own)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating What is the meaning of "no repro" ?

Comment: @Gerard it means "I am not able to reproduce the problem by myself, on my side".

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating ok, I'll try to locate the origin of that call. I've never once faced malware on one of my systems, I blame it on Linux and keeping away of asocial media.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille well might also be something else, can't really know,  but since it's not happening to everyone, don't think it's on SE side.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating The request to cookielaw.org is sent when you hit the button "accept all cookies".  This wouldn't be SE's doing?

Comment: While I don't experience this issue in stock Firefox profiles without extensions, there are a variety of extensions which block requests to load JavaScript from untrusted domains. One such extension which I use, NoScript, will, by default, block JavaScript from any domain unless the settings for the source domain are manually changed. At least with NoScript, it's necessary to first click one of the buttons on the cookie popup. When you do, the request will be made for code from cookielaw, which then puts the domain in the list for which you can choose to allow loading JavaScript, or not.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille you said only "When navigating Stack Exchange" you never mentioned hitting any button. That's very crucial step. Anyway, where you see  "accept all cookies" button?

Comment: It's a div (Your Privacy) that appears at different locations, the technique is called "responsive" I believe.  Right now I've got it as a bar at the bottom of a superuser.com question, next to the "manage settings" button.  No need to look any further, I've found what causes it and I'll add an answer in the morning.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is caused by the fact that I'm using Tor.  The request for "https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js" is answered by a 403 with a page "Error 1020  access denied".  Strangely, a request for "https://cdn.cookielaw.org/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" is answered without problem.

The 403 comes with a content-type text/html and a x-content-type-options nosniff, which causes the console error above.

Comment: I am suffering from this problem as well. Given that it's just loading a static resource, it's bizarre that it would need to block access from Tor.

Comment: The reason usually is that they'd like to know who's reading what.

Comment: I worked around this by "allowlisting" a non-tor direct connection, to cookielaw.org only, in `network.proxy.no_proxies_on` in about:config (found via https://superuser.com/a/1094945).