# How do I dismiss the new cookie popup that appears on the site?

Tags: support, status-declined, user-interface, cookies, cookie-policy

Lately I've been seeing this cookie popup that blocks a lot of the screen.  When I try to do the "manage cookies" thing, all it shows me are several categories, with a green oval containing a black circle to the right of each.  Clicking on that oval makes it disappear.  Clicking on the same spot again makes it reappear.  But I see no indication as to which state is off or on.

So how can I make this popup go away, never to bother me again?  Or failing that, could you at least provide some indication as to what those buttons do?  Like maybe simple text saying "Off" or "On"?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358/we-re-adding-more-user-controls-for-cookie-consent

Comment: No matter how many times I accept the cookies, the pop-up keeps coming. On almost all sites that I visit regularly. It's getting irritating.

Comment: @WrichikBasu then don't keep deleting your cookies ;)

Comment: @Luuklag I don't manually delete any cookies. Probably chrome deletes it. I will have to check it.

Comment: For any devs wondering about why this is status reviewed - *specifically* there seem to be issues with safari as per rene's answer, and this... might make things difficult for a significant part of the SO and SE userbase.

Comment: it's huge, especially annoying when you're on a live CD browser on a small screen

Comment: @jamesqf I've reproduced this issue running Firefox and the extension you've got installed. Ad blocker bugs aside, this use case is unsupported, so I'm setting this to `status-declined`. With all the re-coloring plugins out there, we'll never be able to support those. Did you know we've got our own official dark mode? It's available to users with an account. Check out your preferences and try it out?

Comment: @AaronShekey in defense of the OP , dark mode is only available on SO sites but not on World Building which seems to be their main site.

Comment: @rene fair enough! Someday network sites will get full dark mode.

Comment: @AaronShekey I have no doubt you'll come to the dark-side eventually ;)

Comment: @AaronShekey is there a more precise timeframe then next 6-8 decades, for network wide darkmode?

Comment: @Luuklag No timeline since it'll take me about 6-8 decades to do all the theming _if_ it gets prioritized.

Comment: @Aaron Shekey: Thanks for trying.  I'll just point out, though, that an official "dark mode" for SE only would not seem to do much for me, since I want EVERYTHING I view to appear this way.  (FTM, wouldn't using SE's mode in combination with a plugin just swap everything back to the original?)  WRT the original problem, would not simple text saying "off" and "on" work regardless of mode?  Even in the "light mode" screenshots below, there's no real indication of what having the little circle on one side or the other is supposed to mean.

Comment: Tried the native SE dark mode, went back to Dark Reader. The two main issues is getting the white screen if you happen to not be logged in, and that the native mode just isn't dark enough.

Comment: @jamesqf Use the global-color-inversion of your OS. It's available in some form in in Windows, Ubuntu, MacOS, Android, and iOS. Playing whack-a-mole with trying to get every app and site you use to activate a dark mode is a fool's game, and they always mess it up somehow anyway.

Comment: @tsbertalan: I'm not sure what you mean by global color inversion.  I use OpenSuSE Linux, and have foreground and background colors (and others) set in X, yet many applications, including every browser I've ever tried, cheerfully ignore those settings.  (Well, I think Motif actually did, but that's long, long ago, and the web was different back then.)

Comment: @jamesqf OS theme edits are similarly useless; it needs to be at a lower-level than that. Something like https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087718/easiest-way-to-invert-colors-on-ubuntu-18-04 I don't use OpenSUuSE myself, but a search suggests it's possible there too: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=110152

Comment: @tsbertalan: The problem with that is that I don't really want to INVERT colors, I want to specify the background and foreground (that is, default text) colors.  But I would want other colors to stay the same.  E.g. in a browser I want links to be cyan, visited links to be red.  And specifying colors does work quite well on all the non-browser stuff I use.

Comment: @jamesqf Ah, yes, I personally gave up on that, and judged that the tradeoff was worth it, considering the greater consistency that inversion gives vs the many (universally flawed) dark-mode implementations.

Comment: Stack Overflow just got shamed by John Oliver: <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wqn3gR1WTcA&t=1144>

Comment: Added Hush extension to my Safari browser. No more annoying cookie pop-ups. 

Answer (score 35):

Here’s a uBlock Origin filter to disable it:

```
stackexchange.com##.js-consent-banner
superuser.com##.js-consent-banner
stackoverflow.com##.js-consent-banner
mathoverflow.net##.js-consent-banner
serverfault.com##.js-consent-banner
askubuntu.com##.js-consent-banner
stackapps.com##.js-consent-banner
```

If you don’t read the message, you decline consent by default.

Comment: Thanks.  Now if I knew (or had known, prior to doing a search :-)) what a uBlock filter was, and how to use it, I'd be set.  But I am far from being an expert in javascript (I assume that's what the "js-" means), or really anything to do with web programming.

Comment: @jamesqf You don’t need to know JavaScript; it’s enough to just copy-paste this block of text into your list of custom filters. (Also, use uBlock Origin, not plain uBlock; the latter has been compromised.)

Comment: @jamesqf uBlock Origin is an ad-blocking browser extension that can also be used to block certain HTML elements from being displayed, which is what this answer makes use of.

Comment: @user3840170 I've added the uBlock filter now, but how do I enter those lines? I got the popup removed by clicking "enter select element mode" then clicked the ugly and annoying cookie request, then clicked "create" which created that filter, but I'd like to be able to add them all at once with the lines you gave us here. Also, do you know a solution for android phones?

Comment: Thanks for reporting. This is part of a series of connected bugs that the team is looking into.

Comment: @user1271772 (0) Open uBlock settings, paste this into your list of custom filters (1) Firefox for Android.

Comment: @user3840170 I installed firefox just for this, but the cookie popup still shows up. Do I also need ublock on top of firefox, on my android device?

Comment: I got it working in firefox on Android after installing ublock.

Comment: This seems to be the only thing that works. But in my corporate environment, browser plugins are restricted, as are third-party cookies, so I still get the popup multiple times a day.

Comment: Thank you!  Shame we have to go site by site, but there it is.

Comment: see my answer below for a single line that blocks for **all** SE sites and also blocks the sign in request banner at the top: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381283/382589

Comment: `stackoverflow.com##.js-consent-banner` is no longer working for me.  The following now seems to work instead: `stackoverflow.com###onetrust-banner-sdk`.

Comment: @dbc Huh, never noticed. Maybe because I also have third-party servers like cookielaw.org blocked.

Comment: @user3840170 - it just started today.  And the difference seems to be taking some time to propagate to all of my browser profiles, perhaps because of caching.

Answer (score 12):

> There is a reported bug [cookielaw.org keeps popping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362091/158100) that for iPad / iPhone / Mac (Safari) users this popup always returns on the next page load, no matter what you try. That needs to be fixed first before this answer makes Safari users happy.

You can make the popup go away by clicking *Accept all cookies*

[image]

That will store your choice on your browser.

If you prefer to tune which cookies you allow click *Customize settings* and shows you this dialog:

[image]

In the dialog a setting is ON when the white circle is at the right side of the oval. The oval becomes green. It is OFF when the white circle is at the left side of the oval. The background of the oval becomes grey-ish.

Click the question mark for each category for information on what those cookies are used for.
[image]

Click *Confirm my choices* to generate the two cookies named:

- OptanonConsent
- OptanonAlertBoxClosed

<sub>See this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406384/578411) if you feel for setting these cookies by hand</sub>

Those cookies have an expiration date of a year ahead. So if you never touch that dialog again you might have to re-confirm your settings once a year.

Check the whole cookie list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy#C0001-list)

Once you've set your preferences and later want to revisit or amend your choices, click the *Cookie Settings* link found in the footer:

[image: The cookie settings link is found in the second column named Company, second to last link]

Comment: Excellent use of freehand circles. Worthy of upvoting!

Comment: ... Unless your browser does not store cookies. Or if you block some JavaScript. In that case you are forever cursed with that popup.

Comment: @Quasímodo the other answer nicely addresses that scenario. There is no need for me to repeat that excellent answer here.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Your browser is apparently set to show black/colored text on a white/colored background.  Mine is set to show white/colored text on a black background, which is much easier on my eyes.  As I said, clicking on the ovals simply causes them to disappear.  Further, as a question of basic user interface design, how are people supposed to know which position of the circle in the oval represents off, and which on?

Comment: @jamesqf I'm sorry to hear that. It wasn't clear from your question that you used / applied a different color scheme. Maybe a screenshot can help there and then switch the tags to bug. I assumed you were asking about the functionality the dialog offered and needed assistance in correctly using it.

Comment: @jamesqf I assume you're using a colorscheme that is used by your browser or operating system. Do you mind sharing the browser brand / version and your specific setup so we know what we have to solve?

Comment: When I click the `Customize settings` button on the popup, nothing happens :(

Comment: @KyleVassella are you blocking javascript, for example those from cookielaw.org? Your browser developer console should reveal that.

Comment: I can't make it go away on my iPad. Every refresh, every new page, it reappears. I have not changed any settings and I am not about to just for Stack Overflow. Fix it.

Comment: @user207421 yes, that needs fixing and there is a bug report for: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362091/cookielaw-org-keeps-popping-up/362864#362864 . Just to help diagnose: I assume you're using the Safari browser? Or asked differently: you didn't install or use a different browser on your iPad? If you have installed a second browser (I believe Chrome comes in an native iPad version) can you try reproduce there? You don't need to  login in, the consent dialog is shown to anonymous users as well.

Comment: This is happening regularly on my Windows browser too (Windows 10). I wonder if it's waiting for me to either get sick of it and click accept all (or accidentally click accept all).  But I don't want to accept all cookies thank you very much!  I agree with user207421--it would be nice if StackExchange would fix this rather than make users try to change their settings or do other stuff that we may not understand.

Comment: @rene: I'm using Firefox 60.0 running on OpenSUSE, using an extension called "Dark Background and Light Text", version 0.6.12.

Comment: @jamesqf I installed that extension and the way it changes the colors is incompatible with how the Stacks Design CSS works. I fiddled a bit with the preferences of that extension but I couldn't find a setting that would resolve the issue. If you can't see the toggle, it means it is off. I doubt you will get a resolution for this problem from SE. Maybe the extension maintainer takes suggestions to add options to have some finer control over which elements needs to get their (background) colors overridden.

Comment: @rene: Thanks for looking.  Do you know of some other extension that will do the same thing, and work with SE?  I know very little about extensions and such, and would just like to get a display where I can see everything with a black background.  I have noticed that there seem to be things that other people see that I don't.

Comment: @jamesqf I've not looked into other extensions but if you search for [dark mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=dark+mode) here on Meta you'll find some suggestions. A recent one is  found here https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336626/158100. I didn't check if that particular one solves the specific issue you face.

Answer (score 6):

Following the answer above, add these two lines to a Ublock Origin My filter (click settings icon and then My Filters tab):

```
*##.js-consent-banner
*##.js-dismissable-hero.ps-relative.fc-black-200.bg-black-750.py24.sm\:d-none
*###overlay-header
```

This blocks the cookies banner on all sites that use this code, not just SE sites. It also blocks the sign-in request and the remember to vote for question at the top. Please add to this list if there are more! (use eye dropper icon to pick new banners).

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ublock-origin/ 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en