# Do I have to use a browser plugin to stop being accosted on SE sites with the “Accept all cookies” pop-ups over and over and over? Bug? Options?

Tags: discussion, privacy, cookies

I keep seeing these on SE sites:

> Your privacy By clicking “Accept all cookies”, you agree Stack
> Exchange can store cookies on your device and disclose information in
> accordance with our Cookie Policy.
>
> Accept all cookies Customize settings

The frequency is unreasonable.  Really annoying.  Bug?  What kinds of solutions work?

NOTE: There's some good info at this question of 2 months ago: [The cookie consent dialog (coming from cookielaw.org) keeps popping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362091/the-cookie-consent-dialog-coming-from-cookielaw-org-keeps-popping-up) but it's tagged "status-completed" which is different but similar and related.

I guess I have to upgrade to an AdBlock type plugin with a list for dealing with GDPR/cookie intrusions?   If so, I'm not looking for details on how to do that, as I can google that.  (I don't *object* if specific suggestions or details are provided in addition, but I'm wanting answers to the more broad questions.). (I guess I could lower my browser's privacy settings - which is probably a non-starter, as it's likely to require a over-broad change affecting all websites, not just SE ones, IIRC.)

I'm more asking if there's a setting I can change that will fix this for SE sites (w/o giving SE broad tracking powers.)  Maybe a specific set of cookies that I should allow in the popover?

Like @Ramhound said at the NOTEd question, I have noticed that it’s not due to not accepting all the cookies because the prompt is displayed multiple times in the same browser no matter what combination of the cookies I allow.

I'm NOT getting any error notices @mbauman and @Des noted.

Comment: Clearly this isn't happening to everyone, and isn't the intended behavior. You need to help narrow down exactly what is causing it by sharing more information related to your environment and what potentially is causing your browser to forget that you have already interacted with the cookie popup. If you are unwilling to make the changes required in your settings to stop it, the only other option is to add an adblock-like extension.

Comment: Thanks.  That's good advice.  And I think I found what I needed with a bit more searching, so I added an answer.  (I intend to test and then expand it.)

Comment: interestingly, GA cookies still seem to get generated regardless of whether or not you disabled performance/traffic related cookies.

Answer (score -1):

Oh I found a question the NOTEd question links to that appears to have useful answers: [How do I dismiss the new cookie popup that appears on the site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362697/how-do-i-dismiss-the-new-cookie-popup-that-appears-on-the-site)

There's a filter for disabling it entirely, which declines without the intrusion in one answer

Also, reportedly this is affecting a small % of users; most can just choose and things work, as detailed in a second answer.

Comment: If you found a post asking essentially the same thing after posting, the proper thing to do is flag your question to be closed as a duplicate instead of posting an answer to merely provide the link. If that question is not a duplicate, then this sill isn't an answer. You may include the link in a comment or edit the question and refer to the other post there.

Comment: Agreed.  I debated what to do - whether to post - after I wrote it up.  Then I found and posted an answer and as I noted just before you commented: "I intend to test and then expand it."  I do.  Someone upvoted so I'm torn.  I'll flag it and a mod can decide.