# Please, make "Your privacy" "Accept all cookies" popup smaller, so it will not obscure half of the page

Tags: feature-request, design, popups, cookies

I read numerous questions:

[Do I have to use a browser plugin to stop being accosted on SE sites with the “Accept all cookies” pop-ups over and over and over? Bug? Options?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367896/do-i-have-to-use-a-browser-plugin-to-stop-being-accosted-on-se-sites-with-the-a)

[How do I dismiss the new cookie popup that appears on the site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362697/how-do-i-dismiss-the-new-cookie-popup-that-appears-on-the-site)

[The cookie consent dialog (coming from cookielaw.org) keeps popping up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362091/the-cookie-consent-dialog-coming-from-cookielaw-org-keeps-popping-up)

and resigned to the fact that "Your privacy" popup will stay on forever - clicking "Accept all cookies" slows down browsing a lot and only work until browser restart and I do not want to install extra plugins just to suppress it.
But it should be easy for you to make it smaller, may be put it at the bottom of the page. See [Cookie consent overlay - Does it affect SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121272/cookie-consent-overlay-does-it-affect-seo)

But currently it is a real abomination and covers most of the question/answer box, I have to scroll the page up/down to read few lines of text above the box.
Please, make it smaller!
[image]

Comment: While I completely agree with you, this is a duplicate of this already declined feature request: [Could the cookie banner please be made less intrusive?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362694/could-the-cookie-banner-please-be-made-less-intrusive).