# Why is Stack Exchange using dark patterns on its cookie permission dialog?

Tags: discussion, legal, cookies, gdpr, cookie-policy

It would appear as though Stack Exchange is employing a dark pattern in its cookie permission dialogs.

Specifically, there are two buttons presented in the initial dialog. The colour depends on the SE site on which the dialog is being shown, but in two saturations/shades.

The lighter of the two shades is used in the first dialog to signify the user is **not** okay with all cookies:

[image: Initial cookie consent dialog]

... but then the button using that same lighter shade on the next dialog accepts all cookies and dismisses the dialog with no further confirmation:

[image: Subsequent cookie consent dialog]

Trickery voids consent, which must be freely given on an informed basis.

Comment: It looks like “accept what’s here” is the dark color and “do something different” is the light color. They might have to drop the “Accept All” button on the second dialog altogether because changing the colors and/or positioning of it is just going to be confusing for different reasons.

Comment: It isn't trickery. One is expected to read what the button says before clicking it. And if you accidentally click the wrong one I believe you can undo it to your will.

Comment: The real dark pattern here remains the fact that this dialog shows up ad nauseam, slowly wearing down your will to invest time into customizing settings. Time and time again devs have claimed to fix it, and yet still it persists.

Comment: @Shog9 Are you still getting it on lap/desktop? It shows up every couple of weeks or so on mobile but I haven't been seeing it on my laptops (and mobile browsers have severely limited options for settings).

Comment: @10Rep Out of curiosity, how do you undo it (other than deleting all cookies, I guess)? The setting is not available in any obvious places such as in your profile settings.

Comment: Yes, I still encounter it fairly often on all devices, @BSMP. I've stopped investing effort in trying to figure out why.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek there is a "Cookie Settings" link in the footer.

Comment: Feel free to [block the popup entirely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362698/620615).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [We've added a "Necessary cookies only" option to the cookie consent popup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386727/weve-added-a-necessary-cookies-only-option-to-the-cookie-consent-popup)

Comment: Moving to leave open. While the addition of a button to reject all optional cookies has been added, this post is still valid for users who choose to accept some but not all optional cookies - they can mistakenly click the button with the same shade causing all cookies to be accepted instead of just the ones which the user approved. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386862/377214) to that post indicates that this wasn't changed as part of those changes. (@Makyen)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog The OP posted and accepted a self-answer which is basically a duplicate of the announcement of the changes made with the addition of the "Necessary cookies only" button. That makes it really clear that the OP's question is, in fact, answered by that change and the announcement of that change. There are, of course, somewhat similar questions which could be asked about the now-existing popups, but those would be different questions about different popups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least as of today (2023-03-18), the *Accept all cookies* button is half the width it used to be and there is now a third *Necessary cookies only* button (of the same size and colour as *Accept all cookies* and which has no follow-on dialog) next to it, indicating Stack Exchange finally decided to come into alignment with the relevant regulation.

Better late than never! Thanks to them for finally doing the right thing.

Comment: FYI, please see [We've added a "Necessary cookies only" option to the cookie consent popup](/q/386727).

Comment: Not completely resolved. Users who choose to accept some but not all cookies are still color-tricked into accepting other cookies which they didn't select.

Answer (score 10):

The UX logic is

- Dark = Usual/recommended
- Light = Unusual

In the first dialogue there are two choices. Sure you're encouraged at this point to accept all cookies. That's not really the point of your question, so let's move on. Say you don't click on that and you click on Customise settings instead.

Now we move onto the second dialogue. At this point, the system knows you don't want to accept all cookies, otherwise you wouldn't have reached here at all. So what's the default you're offered at this point - well that's to accept as few cookies as possible to allow the software to work at all. Doesn't that make sense?

In the second dialogue, Accept all cookies is shown lighter, because it would be an unusual choice to make at that point. Why would you choose to accept all cookies when you just told the system you wanted to customise those settings?

Comment: Note that "dark patterns" most broad definition is something designed to favor the shareholder value in detriment of the user value (whenever or not the user is aware of that).

Comment: TBF, that rhetorical question strongly suggests the button doesn't belong on the dialog at all, as it asks a question you've already answered.

Comment: @Shog9 Usually there's some way out if you accidentally pressed a button you didn't mean to though. Could be some way to return to the previous dialogue instead.

Comment: This line of thinking is exactly what the designer of these dialogs was hoping for; it's exactly the reverse of almost every other cookie consent dialog out there, which is why it's so pernicious. SE should be ashamed of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem a bit disingenuous at first glance.  If the UX were coloring based on **Light=Unusual** and **Dark=Usual**, then that would imply that the designer expects a user to read and disregard the "Accept all cookies" button... only to then change their mind and "Accept all cookies."

It's perhaps a dark design pattern... but I'd personally put it in a darker gray zone.  It's certainly not trickery worthy of being an illusory contract.

This is likely a decision to help stakeholders maintain a share of the product.  The product, in this case is the user's lack of privacy.

It's not wicked trickery.  It's just business.  They, like any business, have to pay bills one way or another.

Comment: "...like any business, have to pay bills one way or another." This would kind of imply that without the whole set of cookies StackOverflow as a platform may not survive financially. I doubt that, but maybe cookies are that essential.

Comment: A very good point.  It's quite probable that cookies aren't necessary for the continuation of SO, even as the global leader in their field.

Comment: It looks like the colors have been revisited.  It's not deceptive now.

Comment: And how do the colors look now? Hopefully all options are on equal footing now.

Comment: I personally like it.  I don't know much about UX/etc... but yeah.  it looks good.

Comment: "It looks like the colors have been revisited. It's not deceptive now." Just saw the dialogue, it's still the same. Nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: perhaps I was just part of a pilot feature.. idk.