# The title of the featured question in the sidebar is bugged (again)

Tags: bug, sidebar, community-bulletin, encoding

This is what I see in the sidebar now.

[image]

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386727/1088098) is the question in the picture, and the real title is:

> We've added a "Necessary cookies only" option to the cookie consent
> popup

I'm using Google Chrome Version 110.0.5481.77

Comment: Encoding bugs are becoming a meme at this point. Not a fun one, or a good look.

Comment: It's currently displaying correctly for me (Firefox 110.0)

Comment: @DavidPostill now it displays correctly as well for me. Seems like they have fixed the bug, or the bug just disappeared like last time.

Comment: As the duplicate says, this bug only happens sometimes, not always.