# The cookie popup on international sites has reverted to the old version

Tags: bug, localization, international-sites, cookie-consent-dialog

[11 months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386727/348970), a "Necessary cookies only" option was added to the cookie popup.

But currently this is not working on international sites.
The name of the button is remains "Reject all" (in each language).

> Screenshot of [Portuguese version](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/):
>
> [image: Screenshot]
>
> ("Rejeitar Todos" means "Reject all")

This is not a translation issue.
We already have the correct [translation for "Necessary cookies only"](https://pt.traducir.win/strings/16964).
It is likely that the code running is outdated due to cache or build issues.

---

Also, there are only a few items that can be set in "Customize settings".

> Screenshot of Portuguese version:
>
> [image: Screenshot]

There are only two items.
Originally, there should be four.

> Screenshot of (English) Stack Overflow:
>
> [image]