# Include a "reject all" button in the cookies banner

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, cookie-consent-dialog

#### Proposal

The cookie banner should have a "Refuse All" or, to be more accurate, "Accept Only Essential Cookies" or "Refuse Non-Essential Cookies" or "[insert a label here]" button.

#### Why

It has an "Accept All" button. It is only sensible to have its opposite button.

Although the same can be achieved by going through "Customize Settings", it takes extra clicks and time to reject all cookies, so not having that button is (intentionally or not) a [dark pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_pattern) that induces visitors to click the button which will most swiftly dismiss the annoying banner.

Additionally, it will be a large step to solve [this accessibility problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361009), which is currently (and probably forever) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned).

#### Example

[image: Cookie banner with reject button]

<sup>Made with GIMP.</sup>

Comment: There's a baseline of cookies that are enabled regardless of your choice that allow the site to function. "Reject All" doesn't convey that.

Comment: I would be happy if the “customize” button didn’t select them all by default. Every time I have to deal with that gigantic dialog (which is far more often than I should have to) strong-arming me it to accepting cookies, I get pissed off. I don’t know why I bother, because I’m going to block those cookies myself in my browser, but  it would be nice if a company would stop trying to track me after I’ve told them repeatedly I don’t want them to.

Comment: "Reject Optional Cookies" would probably fit the button.

Comment: I've also seen sites do what ColleenV suggests: unchecking all but the necessary cookies if you chose to customize which cookies you allow. I would also be OK with this, even though a "Reject Optional Cookies" button would be slightly faster.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the "Reject All" options on the cookies is mandatory for European visitors, per European law. The rule is basically that rejecting cookies should be as easy as accepting them. I don't have time to find good English references for that, but for anyone who reads French, see https://www.cnil.fr/fr/nouvelles-regles-cookies-et-autres-traceurs-bilan-accompagnement-cnil-actions-a-venir (CNIL is the French authority that regulates that kind of thing, but I'm pretty sure this is a European law and not just a French one).

Comment: @Dada yes, GDPR mandates the action to be *opt-in*, not *opt-out* (although it does not mandate that there should be an explicit button). And the funny thing about all this is that the toggles for all cookies except necessary are supposed to be *switched off* according to the configuration. That does not mean, of course, that "accept all" being the default button is not a dark practice, though. +1 to the request

Comment: @Dada Expanding on Oleg's, [GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg/2016/679/oj) says *withdrawing* consent should be as easy as giving it. It does not prohibit the consent banner from being much more annoying to dismiss with a rejection of the cookies than with an acceptance of all of them. Probably a site can even block all content while the user does not decide about his consent. Still, I guess such practices are not what one would expect from a mindful site which does not treat its user-base as cash cows.

Comment: "It does not prohibit the consent banner from being much more annoying to dismiss with a rejection of the cookies than with an acceptance of all of them" --> well it does, since rejecting should be as easy as accepting. If the banner is much more annoying to dismiss with a rejection than with an acceptance, then it's not _as easy_... (for anyone wondering, it's in the article 7 paragraph 3 of [GDPR](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/eli/reg/2016/679/oj)).

Comment: @Dada I'd very much like it was so, but it isn't. Quoting that article: "It shall be as easy to withdraw as to give consent." The keyword is withdraw. You can't withdraw a consent you have not given. Withdrawing is different from rejecting. If your interpretation were correct, Stack Inc. lawyers would certain not miss it.

Comment: You might be right (that sounds like a somewhat valid interpretation indeed), I'm not a lawyer. However, almost all websites I visit have a clear "reject cookies" button, even garbage websites (eg, websites with ads everywhere etc). Maybe the people running those websites are just erring on the cautious side of the law, and SE's lawyers did their research and found this somewhat loophole, which I would find very disturbing (I don't think that's a valid loophole though, or at least not as currently implemented: giving consent is still easier than withdrawing since I can't see where to withdraw)

Comment: I think It’s been fixed. Customize correctly lets you opt-in instead of forcing you to opt-out.

Comment: @ColleenV Nope that's not enough for GDPR. If there is an "accept all cookies" button, there _has to be_ a "reject all cookies" button. Nothing less.

Comment: @Dada You're wrong. Or at least I'm going to assume that unless you have some case law that supports your interpretation.  [Make it as easy for users to withdraw their consent as it was for them to give their consent in the first place.](https://gdpr.eu/cookies/) seems to be about revoking consent already given, not initially rejecting cookies. It means you can't allow users to give consent with a button press and require them to send a certified letter to revoke consent. That said, I would prefer a "reject all but necessary" button, but I'm fine with just one extra button press.

Comment: @ColleenV Here is a [document](https://www.cnil.fr/sites/default/files/atoms/files/recommandation-cookies-et-autres-traceurs.pdf) from the french Data Protection Authority (CNIL). Section 2.4, paragraph 31 says that refusing cookies should be doable on the same screen as accepting them, with the same ease, and that if there is a button "accept all", there should be a button "reject all". However, this document contains recommendations and not obligations, which means that the lack of "reject all" button _might_ indeed be lawful.

Comment: Regardless of whether the "reject all" button is mandatory, GDPR clearly states that rejecting/withdrawing should be as easy as accepting. Accepting cookies is a single click on the "accept all" button that is clearly visible. Thus, since there is no "reject all" button, and since there is no "withdraw" button clearly visible and clickable, I don't see how rejecting/withdrawing is _as easy_ as accepting. I agree that clicking on "Customize" - "confirm" is easy, but it's 2 clicks _and_ requires some thinking and thus, its not _as easy_ as clicking "accept all".

Comment: @Dada It would be ideal to use the "Accept all cookies", "Accept only necessary cookies", "Learn more" format I've seen on some sites, but I don't think it's legally required. Being able to customize it more through the cookie settings link is nice, but I'd rather have that somewhere else other than in my face as I'm browsing.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree with the suggestion. I'm not a lawyer nor an expert on GDPR, so I might have been a little bit too assertive in my previous messages. However, I don't see how the current method for rejecting/withdrawing cookies is as easy as clicking "accept all", and thus, I don't think that the current implementation of cookies consent collection of SO/SE respects GDPR. I'll give a call to CNIL (it's the only way to contact them that I found) next week to hear what they have to say; I'll let you know ;-)

Comment: @Dada For me, one button click versus two button clicks is within the rounding error of "easy" because I use a mouse or poke at a screen with my finger. It may not be for someone who is relying on tools to make browsing more accessible, like screen readers or keyboard shortcuts, so I can see the argument, even though for me it's fixed.

Comment: @ColleenV from the CNIL document that I linked earlier, the idea is that if there is a button "accept all" but no "reject all", then people will be biased towards accepting (since it's easier, it allows you to be done with it a move on to the site's content), and that's exactly what GDPR tries to prevent (among other things of course).

Comment: @Dada If you look at the very first comment I left, you'll see that companies trying to strong-arm me into picking the choice that benefits them pisses me off enough to go out of my way to find other means to not do what they would prefer I do. I don't think over-specifying UI is a good idea. Once people see the dialogs on "nice" sites, they'll get annoyed by the dialogs on the "naughty" sites. If someone cares so little about it that they just click the first button they see, that's their choice. We'd have to specify that the order of the buttons is randomized to prevent bias.

Comment: This is now completed and live, see [Updates to the Cookie Consent Banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386727/updates-to-the-cookie-consent-banner).

Answer (score 22):

I would rather see something like this banner:

> [image: screenshot of a cookie consent banner with "cookie settings" link, then a "Reject All" and "Accept All" button]

We don't need "cookies" in the button text. There is a bunch of text already explaining that this is about consenting to cookies. I think "Cookie Settings" is better than "Customize Settings" though, because what I was hoping to see in there was a "never show me this dialog again" setting and was disappointed.

I think for locales which read left to right, the order of "explanatory text", "customize", "reject", then "accept" in a wide banner helps offset the bias toward just clicking the first button.

Unless of course the goal is just to get people to accept cookies instead of giving real consent. Then by all means put a large irrelevant picture, some legal text with most of the information hidden behind a link, then giant "accept" button, then a "customize" button, leave off the reject button and make sure that the dialog obscures a good portion of the content on the page without covering up so much that it's clearly a modal dialog.

Answer (score 10):

It took a while (and some wrestling), but we've finally released a "Strictly necessary only" button in the Consent Banner.

You can find more info in the [official meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386727/updates-to-the-cookie-consent-banner).

Thank you for your patience here, I'm really proud of our team for finally getting this one out!

Answer (score 9):

"Reject all cookies" means rejecting all cookies, including the strictly necessary cookies. The only thing that button will do is close the website from your browser tab because you disagree with all cookies.

An "accept only essential cookies" or "refuse non-essential cookies" button is the feature to be requested, because it is the equivalent of pressing "customize settings", then **inconveniently** waiting for cookies settings to be shown, and pressing "confirm my choices".

However, adding a button that allow people to accept only strictly necessary cookies with one click is bad for advertising. I personally do not think Stack Exchange will add the button unless there is enough pressure from the community to add it.

Comment: "The only thing that button will do is close the website from your browser tab because you disagree with all cookies" - no, it won't. The site can work without cookies, it just won't remember you.