# Winter Bash site shows cookie policy dialog even after logging in

Tags: support, cookies, winter-bash-2021, cookie-policy

Even *after* logging in on the [Winter Bash 2021 site](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/) on a new browser, the cookie policy popup is still shown. Why is this happening? I thought they were stored [across all Stack Exchange domains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362998/295232), and it didn't happen for other Stack Exchange Q&A sites.

[image]

I could reproduce this in the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS Monterey.

Comment: What is your enhanced tracking protection setting in Firefox set to?

Comment: @RobertLongson standard, with no exceptions