# Cookie popup is not responsive on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, cookie-policy

The new "Your Privacy" modal that pops up is not responsive on mobile browsers, causing it to take up two-thirds of the real estate and hang off the edge in Brave on iOS:
[image]

Please fix this on the mobile browser site.

It should take up no more than 1/3 of the real estate and it should be responsive on mobile.

Comment: Repro [on FF Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVeMy.png) 88.0.0-beta.3

Comment: If you want something responsive you should use the full-site, as found in the footer. Mobile-web is something with a limited life-span, so don't expect too much investment into it.

Comment: @Luuklag I'm not even sure it's the 'mobile web'. It's whatever loads up on my browser by default.  I assume by your comment you're saying the "mobile site" and "mobile-web" are different things? That's not confusing at all.

Comment: Thre are two versions you could use when browsing on your phone. By default you use the mobile site, you can opt to use the responsive full-site in the footer.

Comment: @Luuklag I dare ask, would that cause a ... cookie to be dropped?

Comment: At least your site preference is stored by one.

Comment: Related, possible dupe since it's also caused by the thing not being responsive? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362694/369802

Comment: Thank you for reporting. This is part of a series of related bugs that the team is currently looking into.

Comment: Mobile views have been updated so that the cookie banner and modal are mobile-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

[image: screenshot of updated cookie dialog when displayed for Stackoverflow.com]

This has been fixed and the updated cookie dialog is much better.

I think there is still room for improvement in other areas of the UI when displayed on small screens though.