# Allow me to Decline all cookies (one click OptOut button)

Tags: feature-request, privacy

All SO sites currently use this for cookie request

[image]

Allow me to decline all in one click. Add a `Decline All cookies` button.

Comment: You can't decline all cookies. You need the functional ones. So if such button gets added, it should be labelled better.

Comment: Additionally, taken literally, it's not possible to choose to decline on every site, nor save such a preference in your settings: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358/we-re-adding-more-user-controls-for-cookie-consent/359368#comment1199639_359361  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358/we-re-adding-more-user-controls-for-cookie-consent/359368#comment1200377_359495

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to suggest this but didn't think they would bother. Something like [how Reddit does it](https://i.imgur.com/BBmN7nu.png) would be nice. Maybe with a third "customize" button.

Comment: I'm sure cookie preferences can be saved in local storage, why a cookie to store cookie preferences? @41686d6564's idea is also fine.

Comment: I'll take this further. I just need to see a question, and then an answer. Why are the "necessary" cookies even needed? If they're explained, then fine. Till then, let me decline all cookies in one click.

Comment: @B_Dex_Float The "necessary" cannot be declined even with the current pop-up. To see an explanation, click on "Customize settings" and then click on the question mark next to "Strictly Necessary". You can _block_ them using browser settings, an extension, etc., but the website won't function properly... or at all.

Comment: @41686d6564 - If there can be a button to accept all optional cookies there can be a button to decline/deny all optional cookies.  Being able to decline all the optional cookies is helpful since the prompt is displayed multiple times daily within the same browser session.

Comment: @Ramhound I completely agree. See my first comment.

Comment: @41686d6564 I do know the "necessary" can't be declined. I'm saying there needs to be explanation as to why they are "necessary". For example, what is "hero-dismissed" cookie? Why is it necessary? What is "job-visitor-survey-dismissed" cookie doing that breaks the functionality of the site?

Comment: [Related thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363229/665544)