# How can one remove the "Accept all cookies" and "sign up" popups so that they don't appear on SE pages saved on web.archive.org?

Tags: support, cookies, sign-up

[Example](https://web.archive.org/web/20210515214309/https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/140859/my-bank-account-changed-country-and-iban-during-the-year-which-address-and-iban):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With Ublock Origin, just adapt [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359663) by adding these filters:

```
web.archive.org##.js-consent-banner
web.archive.org##.js-dismissable-hero
```

And down with the damn banners!